# How to detect an XSS payload with the lxml library?

Tags: python, lxml, xss

I understand we can use the [`Cleaner`](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/html/clean.py#L109) object, but I don't see any direct reference in the [official repository](https://github.com/lxml/lxml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use this to detect if the payload has XSS content:

```py
clean = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner(style=True).clean_html(document_fromstring(input)).text_content()
```

If the `clean` variable is not equal to `input` so there is XSS content present.

Also, we need to be aware that we need to handle the [`ParserError`](https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html?highlight=parsererror#lxml.etree.ParserError) exception.

More details can be found in the [official documentation](https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.html.clean.html).